# Problema con icheck y evento onclick en linea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estoy usando la librería de `icheck.min.js` y el problema es que el evento `onclik` de mis radio botones ya no funcionan.

El código lo tengo de esta manera:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" role="form" name="fcontacto">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Denominacion (Negocio)</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
       <label>¿Tienes denominación?</label>
       <input type="radio" name="Conocido" id="Conocido_1" onclick="mostrarReferencia();" checked="checked" class="flat-green"> No
       <input type="radio" name="Conocido" id="Conocido_0" onclick="mostrarReferencia();" class="flat-green"/> Si
       <div id="desdeotro" style="display:none;">
         <input type="text" name="denominacion" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" value="N0 ASIGNAD0" class="form-control"/>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- termina form-group -->
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
 //este método ya no se llega a ejecutar, no sé por qué
 function mostrarReferencia() {
   if(document.fcontacto.Conocido[1].checked == true) {
     document.getElementById('desdeotro').style.display= 'block';
     document.fcontacto.denominacion.value = 'N0- ASIGNAD0';
   } else {
        document.getElementById('desdeotro').style.display= 'none';
   }
 }

//Código de icheck que hace que mis radiobotones tomen el color verde
//
$(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"].flat-green').iCheck({
    radioClass   : 'iradio_flat-green'
  })
});
</script>
```

El problema es que no sé cómo implementarlo para que funcione con el `icheck` y que el `onclick` siga funcionando.

Comment: Puedes emular tu HTML/CSS/JS con la herramienta de stackoverflow o sino con jsbin

Comment: @Raul Su respuesta no ayuda mucho

Comment: Cuando dices "_mis radio botones ya no funcionan_", te refieres a que al hacer `click` sobre estos no se ejecuta `mostrarReferencia`, no? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y detalla exactamente que es lo que espera ver y/o que suceda.

Comment: @Marcos ya edité mi pregunta, puedes darle una revisada

Comment: Ya tengo la solución a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Pablo cual es tu solución?

Comment: @Hermann Si lees bien la documentación http://icheck.fronteed.com/ en la parte de los Callbacks existe algo que se llama ifClicked, lo que entiendo es que hace un evento como onclick, MIRA Y LEE LA DOCUMENTACIÓN, $('.flat-green').on('ifClicked', mostrarReferencia); coloca esa linea debajo del $('input')......